# why function return 0 on $this->

Tags: php

I don't understand why my function `getDisplayProductsNewPriceDiscountByQuantity` return 0 then `$new_discount_price` return a price like 600 for example

```
  public function getProductsNewPriceByDiscountByQuantity($id, $qty, $products_price) {
....
      for ($i; $i > 0; $i--) {
        if($qty > $discount_quantity[$i]) {
          $new_discount_price  = ($products_price - ($products_price * ($discount_customer[$i] / 100))) * $qty;

          $this->displayDiscountPrice = $new_discount_price;
          break;
        }
      }

      return $new_discount_price; 
    }


    public function getDisplayProductsNewPriceDiscountByQuantity() {
      print_r('-------' . $this->displayDiscountPrice);
      return $this->displayDiscountPrice;
    }
```

Comment: You´ve posted the wrong function and the question is not very clear (for me)

Comment: `for ($i;` where are you setting `$i`

Comment: Ok the obvious question! Have you called `getProductsNewPriceByDiscountByQuantity()` or some other method that will set a value into `$this->displayDiscountPrice` BEFORE calling `getDisplayProductsNewPriceDiscountByQuantity()`

Comment: no $this->displayDiscountPrice take the value of $new_discount_price and $new_discount_price work fine

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're going for here, but the 2 functions have a slightly different name, and the `$this->displayDiscountPrice` is only set in the top one `getProductsNewPriceByDiscountByQuantity`. So if you call `getDisplayProductsNewPriceDiscountByQuantity` without calling the other function first the `$this->displayDiscountPrice` will be 0

Answer (score 0):

A highly recommended topic to review is the variables scope in general.
This is a great topic, before going deep into OOP and properties scope.

[Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are “undefined variable” errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)